# What is a word for upmost screw up?

Tags: word-request

A common usage word to say that something is screwed up so bad, to the point it cannot be screwed up anymore.
I

Comment: **cked up, ruined, destroyed...

Comment: That's **UTMOST**, not **UPMOST** (the latter isn't actually a word).

Comment: What sort of context are you thinking of.  For example, "screwed up" is vulgar idiom meaning "by being badly managed or carried out." but it also has a simple meaning (when talking about a screw) of being fully tightened.  The answers so far have assume the vulgar meaning,  But it is unclear to me that this is what you mean.

Comment: @JamesK I mean the vulgar context, messed up

Comment: The trouble with this question is there is no single answer… in fact there's a colloquial list so long it will never be completed, as there's a new one every week, as people make their own up & elide/compound different old ones. At the same rate, old ones fall out of fashion, which to borrow from the 80s makes this one *huge* clusterhucknall, pete tong from start to finish.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Upmost is a word, just not the right word. It means uppermost.

Comment: @SegNerd: Hmm. The *full* OED lists three (overlapping) senses (none of which suit OP's context) with *most recent* cited usages 1589, 1620, and 1875. In my book, for the purposes of people wanting to learn English *today*, it's "not a word".

Comment: Related, almost duplicate of a slighly older question on EL&U: [What is the nearest British English equivalent to 'Dumpster Fire'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/591980/what-is-the-nearest-british-english-equivalent-to-dumpster-fire)

Answer (score 1):

There are many expressions with different connotations.

If referring to a situation that is extremely messed up: a **trainwreck**, a **disaster**, (vulgar) a **clusterfuck**...

To emphasize that a thing or situation cannot be saved/improved, you can say that it is **a lost cause**, **a hopeless case**, **damaged beyond repair**, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of decades ago we Brits were quite taken with...

> 1: *[It's a complete]* [***Horlicks***](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2003/07/where-does-the-british-phrase-a-complete-horlicks-come-from.html)  - euphemism for ***complete bollocks***

...but that's since been overtaken by...

> 2: *[It's an]* [***omnishambles***](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-20309441)  - whimsical intensification of ***shambles***

As you'll see if you follow the link above, the Oxford English Dictionary named ***omnishambles*** "Word of the Year" back in 2012. So maybe it's *starting* to tail off by now, but I'm not sure what comes next. Personally, I like [***peak wank***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FpBg0ReuezU) for the *specific* shambolic state of affairs in [inter]national politics today.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, you might hear the word **[fubar](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fubar)**, sometimes written in all-caps as **FUBAR**. It is an acronym, originally used the US military in World War II, that is short for the phrase "fucked up beyond all recognition".